# Existence/Example of numbers which fulfil certain equality of digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Take a number $X = x_1 ... x_n$ where each $x_i$ represents one digit, so that in reality we have
$ X = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot 10^{n-i}$

Now consider the sum $$S = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{x_i}$$ where we define $0^0:=0$. I'm now interested in those numbers that fulfil the equation $X = S$.

I found two examples (and two trivial examples $0$ and $1$):
$X^{(1)} = 3435$. We calculate:
$3^3+4^4+3^3+5^5=3435$ so this number does fulfil the above requirements.
The other example I've found so far is $X^{(2)}=438\:579\:088$.
How can one find more numbers of this type? I wasn't able to come up with an algorithm for that (besides just brute force). Are there infinitely many of those numbers?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A046253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only finitely many and I suspect you have them all.  The most one digit can contribute to $S$ is $9^9$.  The most $S$ can be if $X$ has $n$ digits is $9^9n$, but if $X$ has $n$ digits it is at least $10^{n-1}$.  As $10^{10}-11 \cdot 9^9 \gt 0$ there are no examples with $11$ or more digits.  You still need to check $10$ digit numbers, but you should be able to require they have a lot of $9$s to reduce the search space.

Comment: The only 1-digit numbers I missed is $1$, as $2 \neq 2^2=4$. Nevertheless, thanks for the fast response. I didn't thought about your last point, that is quite a good reason for just finitely many of those numbers

Comment: I  think $0$ counts as well by your definition.  When I wrote the first sentence I was thinking you use the number of digits as the power, not the digit itself.  I have corrected the body as I was off by $1$ digit on the upper bound.  Many problems like this have an upper bound of this sort.  The sum of digits operation is roughly the log of the number and it grows so slowly compared to the number that you can often find an upper bound.

Comment: Yeah I forget to mention these "trivial" numbers. Thanks! Let's see if there are anymore of those numbers